# Unable to set To recipient in Outlook Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, outlook

I am trying to send email using Intent. The code I have written works perfectly for Gmail.I can able to send the email address from my application to Gmail app.But when I try to send email by opening outlook, the **To** email address is not updating. I am using this code in **webview** **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{url});
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email via..."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the URL returned from shouldOverrideUrlLoading already contains "mailto".when i added **mailto:** resulted in a duplicate response of mail.The code works after removing **mailto:**